# NOT EXISTS: Select accounts not assigned to particular project?

Tags: mysql

Ok I have a Project_Assigned table which contain a list of account_ids assigned to a project_id.

Below I am trying to gather a list of all clients that are NOT currently assigned to a specific project.

At the moment the query below works if there are no clients associated with a particular project, but as soon as I assign one client to the project the result set returns nothing when instead it should return all the other clients not assigned to that project.

```
SELECT Account.Account_ID,
Client.First_Name AS `First_Name`, Client.Last_Name AS `Last_Name`, Client.Profile_Pic, Client.Job_Title, Client.Company_Name
FROM Client
LEFT JOIN Account ON (Account.Account_ID = Client.Client_ID)
LEFT JOIN `Admin_Agency` ON (Client.Agency_ID_FK = Admin_Agency.Agency_ID)
WHERE Account.Access_Type = 'Client' && NOT EXISTS 

(SELECT Account.Account_ID, Account.Access_Type
FROM `Project_Assigned` projects
INNER JOIN `Account` ON (projects.AccountID = Account.Account_ID)
INNER JOIN `Project` ON (projects.ProjectID = Project.Project_ID)
LEFT JOIN `Client` ON (Account.Account_ID = Client.Client_ID)
WHERE projects.ProjectID = 48 && Account.Access_Type = 'Client');
```

Table Project_Assigned:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ProjectID | AccountID |
+-----------+-----------+
|         4 |         3 |
|         4 |         4 |
|         4 |         5 |
|         4 |         6 |
|        12 |         1 |
|        12 |        11 |
|        12 |        12 |
|        29 |        18 |
|        31 |        18 |
|        46 |        18 |
|        48 |        18 |
|        48 |        12 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible that I'm misunderstanding your schema, or your needs, but it sounds like you just want this:

```
SELECT Client_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Profile_Pic, Job_Title, Company_Name
  FROM Client
 WHERE Client_ID IN
        ( SELECT Account_ID
            FROM Account
           WHERE Access_Type = 'Client'
        )
   AND Client_ID NOT IN
        ( SELECT Account_ID
            FROM Project_Assigned
           WHERE ProjectID = 48
        )
;
```

No?

Comment: Hi I made a phew tweaks edited the above and now its working. Thanks this really helped.

Comment: @user971824: Your edit doesn't really make sense to me. For example, what is the purpose of the `LEFT JOIN Admin_Agency`? Nothing else in the query actually refers to the `Admin_Agency` table.

Comment: Your right the left join part is actually no longer needed. I accidentally left this behind whilst trying to get it to work.